# How to change database schema in an Azure Mobile App .NET backend?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I've found [documentation on how to change a database schema](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/) for an Azure Mobile Service .NET backend, but I haven't found similar documentation for Azure Mobile Apps.  For those who haven't been paying close attention, Azure Mobile Services was Microsoft's original backend-as-a-service, and it has now been replaced by Azure Mobile Apps.

The documentation I reference above mentions using `ClearDatabaseSchemaIfModelChanges` and `ClearDatabaseSchemaAlways`.  Neither appears to be available in an Azure Mobile App.

How can I start with the quickstart ToDo app and modify the .NET backend to include an additional database column?

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes, the Azure Mobile Apps SDK uses Entity Framework.  You need to adjust your DTO / Model and then add [a database migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).